# Java 8 - How do I merge elements to HashMap

Tags: java, lambda, hashmap

Let me explain my problem scenario.

I am reading one line at a time from a file. I then split the line using a separator and then count the frequency of each word and save it in a map.

Code snippet:

```
Map<String, Integer> frequencyMap = new HashMap<>();
try {
                fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    frequencyMap = Arrays.stream(line.split(PHRASE_SEPARATOR))
                                                            .map(String::trim)
                                                            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.summingInt(e -> 1)));
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

However when I read the next line, it doesn't merge the key-value pairs to the already existing values. How do I ensure that the new key-value pairs are merged while the lines are being read from the file.

Comment: you're overwriting `frequencyMap` at each iteration.

Comment: Yes thats true. I agree. Is there a way to append new key-value pairs ?

Comment: @RahulDevMishra The problem is that you do not want to append, but you want to merge your frequency maps. Entries for next line should not replace current ones, but merge. For example, if this line has 2 "a"s, and the map already has 5, then the new entry for "a" needs to become 7, not 2.

Comment: @devang No, that would replace existing entries in the frequency map.

Comment: @devang - putAll() does';t work. I have already tried it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - Yes you are right. I will edit my question. The keyword is `merge` rather than append.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you need to merge counts as you go, you should read file as a stream of strings, split, and map in a single run, like this:

```
Map<String,Integer> frequencyMap = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))
    .map(line -> line.split(PHRASE_SEPARATOR))
    .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
    .map(String::trim)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.summingInt(e -> 1)));
```

Or use an exception-safe approach:

```
Map<String,Integer> frequencyMap = null;
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
    frequencyMap = stream
        .map(line -> line.split(PHRASE_SEPARATOR))
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .map(String::trim)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.summingInt(e -> 1)));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/RvHdfV)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.
 +1 for the demo.

Comment: Upvoted, I was actually explaining to the OP that this approach is better than mine's

Answer (score 1):

Your code is replacing the frequencyMap on every iteration, so it won't count them all.

Additionally, if the output of your map operation is a list, you can use **flatMap** to add every entry in that list as an entry in the stream. Helps immensely when doing this type of one-to-many relationships.

Something like this might work, haven't had a chance to test it:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class FileReaderTest {

public void main(String[] args) {

    String fileName = args[0]; //sorry, getting lazy here...

    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
        Map<String, Long> frequencyMap = stream
                .flatMap(line -> Stream.of(line.split(LINE_SEPARATOR)))
                .map(String::trim)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Function.identity(), 
                        Collectors.counting()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

A problem with this code is that it will eventually load the ENTIRE file in memory. It is fine for small files, for large files the implementation will be different.

Comment: This doesn't load the entire file in memory. On the contrary, it reads one line at a time. (I'm not sure, but I believe that it actually reads some lines in advance and uses a buffer, but I'd need to read the code to be aware of the full detalis). Nevertheless, I'm sure that it doesn't load the full contents of the file into memory.

Comment: I thought that the "collect" operation on the stream needs all items in the stream before it evaluates. At least this is what I understand from the documentation:

[_"In almost all cases, terminal operations are eager, completing their traversal of the data source and processing of the pipeline before returning."_](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

Is the implementation of Collectors.counting mutating an internal counter in a thread-safe way?

Comment: That excerpt from the docs doesn't mean that `collect` loads the whole stream into memory. It just means that, when most terminal operations are called, the stream is consumed (in the case of `Files.lines`, it is consumed one line at a time). Actually, I have upvoted your answer, because it is correct. What is incorrect, is your last statement.

Comment: This is what it means by *eager*: that the data is traversed from start to end. The docs go on specifying two exceptions for this behavior regarding terminal operations: `iterator()` and `spliterator()`. *Only the terminal operations iterator() and spliterator() are not; these are provided as an "escape hatch" to enable arbitrary client-controlled pipeline traversals in the event that the existing operations are not sufficient to the task.*

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a map for the current line, you should merge it with the map that counts the frequency for the whole file. So, inside your `while` loop, I'd do this:

```
Map<String, Long> lineFrequencies = Arrays.stream(line.split(PHRASE_SEPARATOR))
    .map(String::trim)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Function.identity(), 
        Collectors.counting()));

// Merging of lineFrequencies into frequencyMap happens here
lineFrequencies.forEach((k, v) -> frequencyMap.merge(k, v, Long::sum));
```

Here I've used the [`Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method, which uses the provided function (in this case `Long::sum`) to merge the provided value with the existent value (if the map already had a mapping for the given key), or maps the provided key to the provided value (if the map didn't contain a mapping for the given key).

Note that this code requires you to change your `frequencyMap` from `Map<String, Integer>` to `Map<String, Long>`, which doesn't hurt, IMHO.

Comment: How is this better or optimized than using the brute force naive technique of checking if the key exists, if key doesn't exist then initialise the value with 1 else if key already exists, then get the value and increment.
I mean with this I don't have to create extra map for each line and then do a merge again. What do you think ?

Comment: @RahulDevMishra I answered based exactly on your question, which was how to merge the count of words from one line into the map with the count of words for the whole text file. You were already creating a temporal map for each line, all I did was to merge it into your `frequencyMap`. However, I think it would be better to stream all the lines from the file and then flat map each line to a stream of words, and finally, collect the count of words to your `frequencyMap`. This is how dasblinkenlight has did it.

Comment: Your answer is works just fine. There are no issues with that. This is just an afterthought.
I am solving a question which says that the file size is huge (could be of the order 20GB or more) and hence reading / streaming all the lines at one go will not be good. So i have to read each line at a time. In that context, will this be a good idea or using the naive approach is a better option ?

Comment: @RahulDevMishra `Files.lines()` does not read all the lines at one go. If the stream is sequential, it will read the lines one at a time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. Your answer is equally right, however the answer by dasblinkenlight is just what I was looking for.

Comment: @RahulDevMishra Sure, I agree in that his answer solves your problem in a much better way.